# How to track 'git reset --hard'

Tags: git, github, git-bash

For better understanding I do not want to undo the changes made by 'git reset --hard'. I just want to have a possibility to see, if 'git reset --hard' has been made to a specific branch.
I've tried with 'git log' but it does not show any info on this. After I've used 'git reset --hard ' the latest change according to 'git log' is the commit that the branch was reset to.

Comment: You may be looking for [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).  But note that it will only show things that existed as git objects, so uncommitted changes and untracked files will not be listed.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Thank you!